# How to push json nested object properties to array in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the json object in the following format.

```js
{
  "from": {
    "required": false,
    "type": {
      "name": {
        "required": false,
        "type": "String"
      },
      "email": {
        "required": true,
        "type": "String"
      }
    }
  },
  "to": {
    "required": true,
    "type": [
      {
        "name": {
          "required": false,
          "type": "String"
        },
        "email": {
          "required": true,
          "type": "String"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "subject": {
    "required": true,
    "type": "String"
  },
  "text": {
    "required": true,
    "type": "String"
  },
  "html": {
    "required": true,
    "type": "String"
  }
}
```

In the above object contains multiple nested properties . now i want to push these objects to my array `$scope.fieldsInfo=[]`.
I want to get array in the follwoing format.

```js
$scope.fieldsInfo=[
                      { 
                       "label"    :from,
                       "required" :true,
                       "type"     : [
                                      {
                                        "label" : name,
                                        "type": "String",
                                        "required": false
                                      }
                                      {
                                        "label" : email,
                                        "type": "String",
                                        "required": false 
                                      }                     
                                    ]
                      },
                      { 
                       "label"    :to,
                       "required" :false,
                       "type"     : [
                                      {
                                        "label" : name,
                                        "type": "String",
                                        "required": true
                                      }
                                      {
                                        "label" : email,
                                        "type": "String",
                                        "required": false 
                                      }                       
                                    ]
                      },
                      { 
                       "label"    :subject,
                       "required" :true,
                       "type"     :string 
                      },
                      { 
                       "label"    :text,
                       "required" :true,
                       "type"     :string 
                      },
                      { 
                       "label"    :html,
                       "required" :true,
                       "type"     :string 
                      }
                    ]
```

I tried the following code , but only label and required properties are accessing .

```
for (var prop in data) {
                $scope.fieldsInfo.push({ "label": prop, "required": result.data.hasOwnProperty(prop) });
            }
```